# Filling array / matrix by numbers generated from calculation

Tags: arrays, r, loops, matrix, autofill

I am trying to automate filling of the array / matrix with numbers calculated for an each pair of Facebook pages that I study. I can do this manually by calculating the number for each pair of pages and then fill the array. However, I cannot figure a function that would do this automatically. The example of manual filling:

Sample of rsl:

```
                from_id           from_name      x$likes[, 2]
56924   202099276507678               24.hu  1502184033424382
79551   202099276507678               24.hu   478120425722688
20007   202099276507678               24.hu   910595435726013
574961  543788999005363               ORIGO   918616121589753
172612     308921667047             168 Óra  1225006607529482
46408      131283758531                 HVG   638659559622773
394136  114928525189230     Népszava Online  1021414547939024
20310   202099276507678               24.hu   861515480644047
167859     308921667047             168 Óra  2004057346485378
197230  224510837580985              mno.hu 10207173898839986
51713   202099276507678               24.hu  1094966453889403
342693  543788999005363               ORIGO  1065689316812793
413020  224510837580985              mno.hu  1158229737540788
267020  131059950261988   RTL Klub official   946100758842247
89410   560525343980775            Index.hu   815605101902725
294715  114324688634857              atv.hu  1152065254825682
132637  731815466835029 The Budapest Beacon  1125893650794568
389574     308921667047             168 Óra   954405207961450
928211  114324688634857              atv.hu  1116577471733852
118642     131283758531                 HVG  1178121435555294
152663  543788999005363               ORIGO   690312584444943
29586   560525343980775            Index.hu  1768701566700483
2066110    248494883317                 TV2  1031371220285102
657501     308921667047             168 Óra  1740704569476190
400491  560525343980775            Index.hu  1083676221692203
```

Calculation and manual filling:

```
media <- unique(rsl$from_name)
v<- matrix(nrow=length(media), ncol=length(media))
colnames(v) <- c(media)
rownames(v) <- c(media)

mf <- function(a, b) {
  ua <- rsl[rsl$from_name==a, "x$likes[, 2]"]
  ub <- rsl[rsl$from_name==b, "x$likes[, 2]"]
  pa <- length(ua)
  pb <- length(ub)
  pab <- length(intersect(ua,ub))
  return(c(pa,pb,pab))
    }

le <- mf(a=media[1], b=media[1])
M <- 2200000

NFD <- (max(log10(le[1]), log10(le[2])) - log10(le[3]))/(log10(M) - min(log10(le[1]), log10(le[2])))
v[1,1] <- NFD
```

I would just basically change the pair in the "le" and then insert the resulting value in the matrix.

I tried something like this:

```
v <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(media), ncol=length(media))
for (i in seq(media)) {
  for (j in seq(media)) {
    le <- mf(a=unique(media), b=unique(media))
    NFD <- (max(log10(le[1]), log10(le[2])) - log10(le[3]))/(log10(M) - min(log10(le[1]), log10(le[2])))
    v[i,j] <- NFD
    }
  }
v
```

Obviously, there is a mistake but I could not make it to work as I want to. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that the only values in your for loop dependant on i and/or j are the output location? I assume you want different input variables to your le function for each run of the loop, but I'm not seeing where that happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, the problem is that I cannot find the way how to make that work. I was for every iteration in the loop to use the different pair of media and calculate their value. So for instance, a=media1, b=media2, calculate and insert in the array. Second, a=media1, b=media3, calculate and insert on in the array and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you wish to add the variables extracted from "media" into your calculation, but you'll need to refer to those values as a specific reference within, for example:

```
media[i]
```

rather than:

```
media[1]
```

That way, the "i" will cycle through all possible values given in the for loop call (in your case "seq(media)", although I'd usually use "1:length(media)" myself). So, for the "le" line, you'd need something like:

```
le <- mf(a=media[i], b=media[j])
```